# Symbol not found: _PQclear (caldav server tools broken after Mavericks update on OSX Server)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, osx-mavericks, caldav, osx-server

After upgrading my server to Mavericks and Server.app version 3, those tools stopped to work properly :

**calendarserver_export**
**calendarserver_manage_principals**
...

When I enter this command, for example :

```
sudo calendarserver_export -u <account_name>
```

then this error is displayed :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/calendarserver_export", line 32, in <module>
    from calendarserver.tools.export import main
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/calendarserver/tools/export.py", line 50, in <module>
    from calendarserver.tools.cmdline import utilityMain, WorkerService
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/calendarserver/tools/cmdline.py", line 21, in <module>
    from calendarserver.tap.caldav import CalDAVServiceMaker, CalDAVOptions
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/calendarserver/tap/caldav.py", line 87, in <module>
    from twistedcaldav.upgrade import UpgradeFileSystemFormatStep, PostDBImportStep
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/twistedcaldav/upgrade.py", line 63, in <module>
    from calendarserver.tap.util import getRootResource, FakeRequest, directoryFromConfig
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/calendarserver/tap/util.py", line 87, in <module>
    from txdav.base.datastore.subpostgres import PostgresService
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/txdav/base/datastore/subpostgres.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pgdb
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/pgdb.py", line 66, in <module>
    from _pg import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/_pg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQclear
  Referenced from: /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/_pg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/_pg.so
```

All these tools have in common to access the caldav data via python, through PyGreSQL (caldav data is hosted in a postgres database).
I managed to reproduce very simply this problem by :

```
#login with root
bob $ sudo -i
#launch python and import pg (postgres module for python)
root $ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyGreSQL-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pg.py", line 31, in <module>
    from _pg import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyGreSQL-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_pg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQclear
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyGreSQL-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_pg.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyGreSQL-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_pg.so
```

**BUT**, if I launch python from my user account (not root), **I don't get the error**.
I assume there is something wrong with the path, or something similar, but I can't find what...
I need to have root credentials to be able to use **calendarserver_export**

Any clues ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, in mavericks, you have to launch these commands with the "calendar" user (alias of _calendar).

So the command should be : 
sudo **-u calendar** calendarserver_export -u